# Ctrl+A does not work in all programs

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

I use Ubuntu 11.10. And I have a big problem.

In some programs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> doesn't work. For example in Chrome <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> doesn't work; only in text areas. In Gedit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> doesn't work at all. In Qutim <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> works well.

Answer (score 11):

Here is ansver: http://ubuntovod.ru/ask/discussion/58/ne-rabotaet-ctrl-a-v-ubuntu-11.10

In eng: run gnome-tweak-tool, "theme", and change key theme. This:

[image]

Hope i help somebody. :)

Comment: You helped me, mate ;) +1.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too, but with Gnome 3.10.

After reading the @Sk8er, I found my mistake, the Key Theme should not be EMACS.

To fix it:

Run `gnome-tweak-tool` > `Keyboard and Mouse` > `Key Theme`

Set the `Key Theme` value to `Default`.

[image: gnome-tweak-tool screen]